# Installing ESX 4.1 on 1.8 GB Of RAM

Tags: esxi

Can anyone help me install ESX4.1 on 1.8 GB of RAM. Currently, it is giving me an error that I can only install ESX 4.1 on 2 GB RAM, and my VGA take 128 MB of my RAM.

Can anyone help me install ESX 4.1 on 1.8 GB of RAM?

Comment: I'm not trying to throw money at the issue, but I think that the easiest (and possibly only) solution would be to install more RAM. VMWare probably won't really help you out with that if you call them either. Good Luck...

Comment: I'd like to put 10 pounds of dirt in a 5 pound bag, but some things just can't be done. Buy and install more RAM is the answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah i have to, and i already install 2 More GB of RAM

NEW ISSUE : need another NIC card
i wanna buy also which is good and cheap guys?

Comment: Intel PRO/1000 works fine with ESX/ESXi and VLANs.